# (Javascript) Get substring in the string and replace it with another

Tags: javascript, substring

I have a string like this (javascript):

```
var str = "Just the way you are";
```

1) I want to get the substring from startIndex to endIndex like this:

```
str.getSubstring(startIndex, endIndex);
var result = str.getSubstring(5, 7); //result will be "the";
```

2) And I also want to replace the substring like this:

```
str.replaceSubstring(startIndex, endIndex, stringToReplace);
str.replaceSubstring(5, 7, "hello");// str will be "Just hello way you are";
```

Thank for your help.

Comment: Ofcourse you tried loads of methods to get at the desired result. Show them, shows us what's not working ... and maybe we can help you.

Comment: Actually, I can write these functions, but It will be so long and not good. I want a beautiful code for these functions. Thank for your help.

Comment: [You're looking for string.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Replace).  I'm assuming you're searching for the word "the" in this case, not necessarily a specific index range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String.prototype.replaceSubstring 
    = function (startIndex, endIndex, stringToReplace) {
        return this.replace(
            this.substring(startIndex, endIndex + 1), 
            stringToReplace
        );
    };

var str = "Just the way you are";
alert(str.replaceSubstring(5, 7, "hello"));
```

You may try it here: **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v8k2zjqr/4/)**

**Note** that you don't have to call it like this

```
str.replaceSubstring(str, 5, 7, "hello");
```

Why to pass `str` again to itself ?
You are already calling it from `str` instance

In my function just call it as

```
str.replaceSubstring(5, 7, "hello");
```

Comment: wow that's pretty complicated for what he wants to do. besides, you generally don't want to fiddle with the build in object's prototypes

Comment: He wants to call this function from the string instance, check PO question, he is aiming to this signature : str.replaceSubstring( .... ); ... BTW, there is no problem in adding a function to string prototype (adding is not overwritting existing behavior which not preferred for maintenance), in fact it's better to extend it with new functionality and get use of JS' OOP capabilities

Comment: Could you answer me the question 1?

Comment: Simply use `str.substring(startIndex, endIndex + 1)`, for example ...  `var result = str.substring(5, 8)` ... note that when you want character at index `7`, you have to add an extra 1 to the function to be `8` ... if this solves your question, mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you are looking forward to

```
var str = "Just the way you are";
var finatStr = str.replace(str.substr(5,3), "hello");
```

Here method substr(startIndex, length/*instead endIndex*/)

find fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/resvuw6p/)